# Endpoint is not supported

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face

I am trying to use the Face API of Microsoft Cognitive services. 
And when I attempt to consume createALargeFaceList, I receive: 
Enpoint https://mycompany.cognitiveservices.azure.com/ is not supported.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Pls have a check that if you created a Face API service correctly on Azure portal :

[image]

Comment: Hi @AmirN , if my answer is helpful for you , pls click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark it as an answer. Help you have a nice day !

Comment: could you remove your key from that image?